# dynamic string interpolation

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I would like to pretty-print a `Product`, such as a `case class`, so I create the following trait:

```
  trait X extends Product {
    def fmtStrs =
      productIterator map {
        case _ : Double => "%8.2f"
        case _ => "%4s"
      } map (_ + separator) toSeq
    override def toString = {
      new StringContext("" +: fmtStrs : _*) f (productIterator.toSeq : _*)
    }
  }
```

This uses string interpolation as described in the ScalaDoc for [StringContext](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.StringContext).

But this won't compile, with this cryptic error:

```
Error:(69, 70) too many arguments for interpolated string
      new StringContext("" +: fmtStrs : _*) f (productIterator.toSeq : _*)
```

Is this  a bug, or limitation of a macro? Note that doing the following works fine, so I suspect this may be related to the variable argument list:

```
scala> val str2 = StringContext("","%4s,","%8.2f").f(1,23.4)
str2: String = "   1,   23.40"
```

Comment: Rather bizarrely, if you change the `f` interpolator to the `s` interpolator, this appears to complie (and work) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `f` is a macro is so that it can give you an error when types of format specifiers and arguments don't match, and this isn't possible to check by looking at `("" +: fmtStrs : _*)` and `(productIterator.toSeq : _*)`, so it isn't particularly surprising this doesn't work. The error message could be clearer, so let's see what exactly happens.

If you look at [the implementation of `f`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/compiler/scala/tools/reflect/FormatInterpolator.scala#L25) (it took me some time to actually find it, I finally did by searching for the error message), you'll see

```
c.macroApplication match {
  //case q"$_(..$parts).f(..$args)" => 
  case Applied(Select(Apply(_, parts), _), _, argss) => 
    val args = argss.flatten
    def badlyInvoked = (parts.length != args.length + 1) && truly {
      def because(s: String) = s"too $s arguments for interpolated string"
      val (p, msg) =
        if (parts.length == 0) (c.prefix.tree.pos, "there are no parts")
        else if (args.length + 1 < parts.length)
          (if (args.isEmpty) c.enclosingPosition else args.last.pos, because("few"))
        else (args(parts.length-1).pos, because("many"))
      c.abort(p, msg)
    }
    if (badlyInvoked) c.macroApplication else interpolated(parts, args)
```

With your call you have a single tree in both `parts` and `argss`, and `parts.length != args.length + 1` is true, so `badlyInvoked` is true.

`s` doesn't care what its arguments look like, so it's just a method and your scenario works.

Comment: Thanks; for the record, just ended up calling `java.lang.String.Formatter` directly instead of using string interpolation.